# Do nightclubs have scoreboard for waitresses?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, mollys-game

In *Molly's Game* (2017), Dean, who is regular to the club, speaks to Molly,  a waitress at club:

> Dean: People seem to take to you. How would you like to get paid to
> go to grad school and get an MBA in how life works?
>
> Molly: What makes you think you know and I don't?
>
> Dean: I'm a regular here, and you're a waitress here. Look at the
> fuckin' **scoreboard**.

Do nightclubs have scoreboard for waitresses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dean is <s>being a dick</s> referrring to the *metaphorical* scoreboard.

In his opinion he's winning **at life** because he's monied and can afford to come to the nightclub regularly. By comparison, she's losing because she has to work as a waitress serving him.

There's no literal scoreboard.

Answer (score 1):

"*Look at the fu***' scoreboard*" is just a basic way to say: see how far ahead/behind you are?!

It's used mainly in sports, when someone is bragging about a nice play, and the lad on the other team just throws him a "look at the scoreboard mate" kind of look (or word or finger move) to indicate that it doesn't count *that* much, because despite of your efforts, you're still loosing. BIG.

In the case of Molly, he just belittles her position compared to his.

Sometimes, you can use it to motivate someone who is far ahead but lacks confidence and think he's behind. But it's mostly the other way around though.